# AudioRecord - empty buffer

Tags: android, audiorecord

I' m trying to record some audio using AudioRecord class. Here is my code:

```
    int audioSource = AudioSource.MIC;
    int sampleRateInHz = 44100;
    int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int bufferSizeInShorts = 44100;
    int bufferSizeInBytes = 2*bufferSizeInShorts;

    short Data[] = new short[bufferSizeInShorts];
    Thread recordingThread;

    AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource,
                                                sampleRateInHz,
                                                channelConfig,
                                                audioFormat,
                                                bufferSizeInBytes);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        public void startRecording(View arg0) {
                audioRecorder.startRecording();
                recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (Data[bufferSizeInShorts-1] == 0)
                                audioRecorder.read(Data, 0, bufferSizeInShorts);
                    }
                });
                audioRecorder.stop();
        }
```

Unfortunately my short array is empty after the recording is over. May I kindly ask you to help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: you should test the return value of read to figure it out. (That's what return values are for. giving you a clue of what happened.). Also, testing the last value for 0 may not work as 0 is a valid value.

Comment: You are right about testing the last value - i will have to find different solution. However even with that testing I should get something written to my short array. .read() function returns 0 which means that there was nothing copied into my short buffer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Comment: aren't you supposed to use a OnRecordPositionUpdateListener ?

Comment: If i understood correclty OnRecordPositionUpdateListener should be used when data from AudioRecord buffer is read periodically. In my case it supposed to be read only once since AudioRecord buffer and my short array have same size.

Comment: I just read your code again, properly this time, and it is actually quite simple : A/ you start and stop the recording in a matter of nano seconds. B/ you create a thread to read the record, but you don't start it.

Comment: Thanks - I've added line that calls thread starting method. About stopping recording immediately - I thought that recording process will last as long as WHILE execution. With sampling frequency = 44.1kHz and short array size = 44100 whole recording operation should take 1 second. Maybe I'm missing something here ... May I kindly ask you to suggest me how to extend recording process period?

Comment: it stops immediately because the thread is executed in another thread (that's what they do), and therefore does not block the method execution. You may need to call the stop in the thread, for instance after your while loop

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this code can help you lot better with the desired Example:-[Link with Example](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/10/play-audio-file-mp3-from-asset-folder.html).

Comment: I'm not sure how it is suppose to help me since it's a mp3 player realized with MediaPlayer class.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.This is the link through which you can solve your problem.I hope it helps.The link is as follows:-[link](https://sites.google.com/site/mojabdelhadi/technical-tutorials/android/android-audio-recording-tutorial)